# Why can WindowManager.LayoutParams.token be equal to ViewRootImpl.mWindow.asBinder?

Tags: android, android-binder

In `WindowManagerGlobal.addView`, there is such a statement:

```
if (mRoots.get(i).mWindow.asBinder() == wparams.token)
```

I'm confuesd here. `ViewRootImpl.mWindow` is an instance of `IWindow.stub`, but `WindowManager.LayoutParams.token` is an instance of `IApplicationToken.stub`. How can they be equal?

Could anyone explain this?

Comment: `wparams.token` is an `IBinder` and `asBinder()` method returns `IBinder`

Comment: @pskink yes I know they are both `IBinder`. But they extends different `Binder` as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: so the `if` code will not be executed in that case... what is the issue?

Comment: @pskink then in what condition will the `if` statement be satisfied?

Comment: when you have the same object on the both sides of `==` operator